# swift: animation with buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiviewanimation

I use this code to create animation with button:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        self.button1.constant = self.button2.constant
    case 6:
        self.button3.constant = self.button4.constant
    default:
        self.button1.constant = 0
        self.button3.constant = 0
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0,
                   options: [], animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

I have `collectionView`. But with my buttons my `collectionView` animated too. How to do that I have animation only with button?

This code doesn't work:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0,
               options: [], animations: {
                self.myButton.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.myButton1.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

Comment: call layoutIfNeeded on your cell instead of self.view

Comment: cell.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: @ShahzaibQureshi I get same result

Comment: What exactly should the animation do? I don't see any code that is actually changing view components in your `animations: {}` block

Comment: @Rob animation should move the buttons under screen edge. Update question.

Comment: Assuming `button1`, `button2` and `button3` are instances of `NSLayoutConstraint` and are setup the right way, your code looks correct to me. Could you share the parts where you define these constraints, either in your code or in Storyboard? Also, could you share the animation of your `collectionView`?

Comment: @Rob I add full code. I haven't any animation in `collectionView`. My problem is - `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`? All view animated.

Comment: The thing is you are animating the constraints, but these constraints might be setup in the wrong way, e.g. the constraint are between your `collectionView` and something else. Can you share the definition of the constraints?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177742/discussion-between-rob-and-user).

Comment: Please don't edit your question by adding empty spaces just to bring it to the top of the list of questions.

Comment: @Rob Everything works fine if use `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` instead `self.view.layoutSubviews()`. Is this a good solution or not?

Comment: Sure, I guess if it works I don't see any issue besides potentially redrawing/layouting the subviews when it is not needed. Maybe someone has some more insights on this?

Comment: You should show what your constraints are. Share you storyboard or the code where you set the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Try to subclass `UICollectionView` and override `layoutSubviews` method as below:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
     UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
         super.layoutSubviews()
     }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0,
                       options: [], animations: {

        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            self.button1.constant = self.button2.constant
            self.myButton1.layoutIfNeeded()
        case 6:
            self.button3.constant = self.button4.constant
            self.myButton3.layoutIfNeeded()
        default:
            self.button1.constant = 0
            self.button3.constant = 0

            self.myButton1.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.myButton6.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed this code working.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = cell as? MyCollectionViewCell else { return }

    cell.yourConstraint.constant = 10 //desired value

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

I think your problem is that your constraints called 'button1', button2' and so on are hooked to your view controller's view or the collectionView.

You have to set up the constraint between the button(assumably inside the collection view cell) and the collection view cell's contentView, AND have that constraint property in the custom UICollectionViewCell class.